# Why does Ubuntu use this horrible pattern of colors?

Tags: colors, design

I believe Ubuntu could have more new users if it simply used a more beautiful and more neutral color pattern like OS X and other Linux distributions. So why does Canonical use these colors?

Comment: I don't mind them... Also, if you don't enjoy Unity, why not install Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Lubuntu, Ubuntu GNOME, Budgie, or any of the other flavors with different Desktop Environments? We aren't actually Canonical employees here (though some users are), so we can't answer this question.

Comment: Just because you don't like them doesn't mean that everyone else has the same opinion.

Comment: But you guys must agree that orange, purple and friends aren't the best option to get people first impression and make then try a new OS.

Comment: Actually, no, I do not. It's Ubuntu's signature flair. If you don't like it, again, that doesn't mean everyone else agrees.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I agree with you soooo often... but in this case I don't like the colors either.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix you're just proving my point ;) -- different opinions.

Comment: BTW, you can change the theme if you really hate the default. I'm using a Numix icon theme and RavenFinity window theme.

Comment: And of course, the colour scheme is there to deter those who might come to Ubuntu for its appearance rather than its substantive qualities. ;-)

Comment: Well...It's the Ubuntu's orange color, that attracted me first to this distro! What would you say about me then?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this. It asks *why* a specific and important design decision was made. Its answer is complete, drawing entirely from official sources. How could we have known it was objectively answerable? True, not every design decision at every level can be explained here. But the branding and color choices in Ubuntu are well thought-out and it's typical for Ubuntu developers to explain aspects of Ubuntu that distinguish it from other OSes. (As a secondary consideration, its current closed status expresses the wrong idea that there is no discernible reason Ubuntu looks the way it does!)

Answer (score 13):

The reasoning can be seen at [the Ubuntu Design site](https://design.ubuntu.com/brand/colour-palette):

> ## Ubuntu core colours
>
> The Ubuntu colour palette has been created to reflect the spirit of
>   our brand. Orange for a community feel. White for a clean, fresh and
>   light feel.
>
> Black is used in some versions of the brandmark for flexibility of
>   application and where print restrictions apply. It can also be used
>   for body copy.
>
> ---
>
> ## Neutral colours
>
> ### Warm grey
>
> For balance. The addition of warm grey softens the combination of
>   orange and aubergine and provides a bridge between the two.
>
> Warm grey can be used for; backgrounds, graphics, pictograms, dot
>   patterns, charts and diagrams. It can also be used for large size
>   text.
>
> ### Cool grey
>
> For typography, particularly body copy. Black can be quite harsh in
>   combination with aubergine, but grey delivers more balance while still
>   being legible.
>
> Cool grey can also be used within charts and diagrams.
>
> ---
>
> ## Canonical core colours
>
> The Canonical colour palette has been created to reflect the spirit of
>   our brand. Aubergine for a smart, focussed feel. White for a clean,
>   fresh and light feel.
>
> ---
>
> ## The amount of colour we use
>
> Our colour palette consists of orange, aubergine, white and warm grey.
>   The amount of colour we use for community and Canonical collateral
>   varies according to the emphasis of the content.
>
> At one end of the scale, where the work is dominated by the community,
>   the emphasis is on a fresh palette, the use of white and orange, and
>   warm grey for balance. Aubergine is used only as a highlight.
>
> At the other end of the scale, where the work is more focused on
>   Canonical, the palette is more refined and grounded, with much more
>   emphasis on aubergine as the core colour. Orange is only used as a
>   highlight and we use white and warm grey to complement the orange and
>   aubergine.

Whether you like them or not is, of course, up to you.